# Why I am getting default date value when i try to format the date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I used the following code to format the date to format like "MM/dd/YYYY"

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY"];
NSString *dateString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSdate date]];

NSString *dbDate=@"08/03/2013";


NSDate *currentDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSDate *newDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dbDate];
NSLog(@"currentDate is %@",currentDate);
NSLog(@"newDate is %@",newDate);
```

but i am getting the console output like follows

> currentDate is 2013-01-04 18:30:00 +0000
>
> newDate is 2013-01-04 18:30:00 +0000

But i was expecting ouput like the following

> currentDate is 11/22/2013
>
> newDate is 08/03/2013

Can anyone correct my mistake

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLog of NSDate  is always in this format :

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +timezone
2012-12-23 18:30:00 +0000
```

If you want in `11/22/2013` format, you need to convert the date into `NSString` and log that string.

Also, you had couple of mistakes, please use this code :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSString *dbDate=@"08/03/2013";
NSDate *currentDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSDate *newDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dbDate];

NSLog(@"currentDate is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]);
NSLog(@"newDate is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

*Output:*

```
currentDate is 11/22/2013
newDate is 08/03/2013
```

Comment: I understand, but still i am not getting the date i expected, i am getting only the date 2013-01-04  and not 2013-11-22

Comment: becouse of your YYY, use yyyy

Comment: @surendher: ple read Lord Zsolt answer as he said no need to converted 3-4 times between date->string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the string you want to display:

```
NSLog(@"currentDate is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentDate]);
```

your date format should be:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. There's no need to convert [NSDate date] to string, then back to NSDate, then back to string for output.

Also you wrote YYY instead of yyyy

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSString *dbDate=@"08/03/2013";

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *newDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dbDate];
NSLog(@"currentDate is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate]);
NSLog(@"newDate is %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

Comment: Liked your words as no need to converting date->string->date->string :) But it may be that he is using it in different method calls. He may not have only these 8 odd lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, most likely he just left it there for testing, though one of each is enough :)